# DataGridView - setting object's displayed value in a column

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I bind some collection to a **DataGridView**. Collection contains **KeyValuePair** objects where key is a string and value is an object of my class **Field**. **DataGridView** displays two columns - one containing the key and the other one containing the value. The value (**Field** object) is displayed with its **ToString**() method. But I would like it to be displayed using its Name property. The problem is the column contains no **DisplayMember** property.
How can i do it?

Edit: I know I could override ToString() to return the name of the object but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridView` (in common with most direct list-based bindings) can only bind to immediate properties of the row item. You could perhaps create a facade object for this? i.e. a class that accepts the instance and returns the name as a direct property:

```
public string Name {
    get {return innerObject.Name;}
    set {innerObject.Name = value;}
}
// snipped: other properties - Key etc
```

Alternatively, you could project into a new object? For example, data-bindings work (read-only, at least) with anonymous types pretty well:

```
grid.DataSource = originalData.Select(x=>
    new {x.Key, Name = x.Field.Name}).ToList();
```

Finally, you can hack around in `ComponentModel` to flatten the model at runtime, but it **really** isn't worth it just for this.

Comment: yeah i know it just shouldn't be used like this - i mean datagridview should simply display the property of the object in a column, but i hoped there was some way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the DataGridView into virtual mode (view.VirtualMode = true), and handle the CellValueNeeded (and possibly the CellValuePushed) events to access the "Name" property.  This would avoid creating lots of wrapper objects, but does make the code somewhat less elegant.